# Plotly dash cant cannot callback secondary Yaxis dynamically

Tags: plotly, plotly-python

I try to invent a biomonitoring app for my University. Maybe there is someone here who has some time. I have a graph which is created from measurement data. For the graph you can select columns to be displayed and you can select which columns are on the first or second y axis. The code and the csv file for the pandas dataframe is on the Github repo:
link:
https://github.com/yotestyo/dash

Maybe someone have time to resolve this problem, i would pay 10 bucks in paypal

Unfortunately the code does not work properly and I get errors if i select or unselect different y_axis, the following java script error:

l.gridlayer is undefined

Comment: Problem seems to go away if you remove the line beforn your return the figure `fig.update_layout(transition_duration=500)`. Not sure what is happening here exactly though.

Comment: Thanks, how can i contact you? i dont have a linkedIn account